# Unable to change the frame of the image a default style UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, arrays, uiimageview, uitableview

Maybe it is not possible to do this... I'm trying the following line (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method), with no success:

```
cell.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,10,5)
```

Is there any way to do that? Or I just need to implement a custom cell view?

Thanks

Comment: Subclass UITableViewCell

Comment: Try putting that line in the `willDisplayCell` method instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @rmaddy I just tried and it didn't work for me...